# Linux shell - Sort on a numerical column

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

I'm using the linux shell in a jupyter notebook. I'm trying to filter rows of a .csv file to only keep those including 'Government expenditure on education, total (% of GDP)', then to only keep columns 1 and 64, and finally to sort based on column 64 which is numeric.

```
grep 'Government expenditure on education, total (% of GDP)'  WDIData.csv | cut -d ',' -f 1,64 | sort -t "," -k64n
```

However, it keeps sorting it Alphabetically based on column 1:

```
"Afghanistan","3.19979000091553"
"Africa Eastern and Southern","4.95163488388062"
"Africa Western and Central","3.0132200717926"
"Albania",""
"Algeria","5.8663501739502"
"American Samoa",""
"Andorra","3.2467200756073"
"Angola","2.04470133781433"
"Antigua and Barbuda","2.64407563209534"
"Arab World",""
"Argentina","4.87773990631104"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two wrong things, maybe three:

1. Your `sort` gets the output from `cut` and this output *only*. In the output from `cut -d ',' -f 1,64` there are *two* fields.
2. `"3.19979000091553"` and similar strings cannot be sorted numerically like you expect because of the leading `"`.

   If there is always `"` as the 1st character of the 2nd (originally 64th) field then `-k2.2n` should work.
3. Your locale (you did not disclose it) may or may not recognize `.` as a decimal separator. When in doubt, use `LC_ALL=C`:

   ```
   … | LC_ALL=C sort -t , -k2.2n
   ```